# Pass multiple functions to map_dfr:map

Tags: r, dictionary, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to read several CSV files from the AWS database and only keep records for the oldest date in each .csv file (each CSV file contains the last eight days and only the oldest date is final data). Let' say file A contains data from 06 till 14 May, I want to filter the only record for 06 May from file A, Only 07 from file B and so on

I am using `map_dfr` to read data from the AWS database, but how can I pass multiple functions to `purrr::map_dfr`. My snippet will run without error but It will keep all the date/records so `~ min(lubridate::ymd(data_date))` seems not process

```
df  <-  map_dfr(
  objects,
  ~ s3read_using(
    FUN = read_csv,
    object = .x,
    bucket = "my_bucket"
  ),
  .id = 'Date' , ~ min(lubridate::ymd(data_date)) )
```

Comment: you can pipe them `%>%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on paqmo's comment:

```
library(aws.s3)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df <- map_dfr(
  objects,
  ~ s3read_using(
    FUN = read_csv,
    object = .x,
    bucket = "my_bucket"
  ) %>%
    mutate(data_date = lubridate::ymd(data_date)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(data_date == min(data_date)),
  .id = 'Date'
)
```

Or somewhat clearer (maybe):

```
read_from_s3_and_process <- function(object) {
  s3read_using(
    FUN = read_csv,
    object = object,
    bucket = "my_bucket"
  ) %>%
    mutate(data_date = lubridate::ymd(data_date)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(data_date == min(data_date))
}

df <- map_dfr(
  objects,
  read_from_s3_and_process,
  .id = 'Date'
)
```